# How to find the summation of a fraction?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\sum\limits_{i=400}^{2000}  2^{3 - 4k}/8^{2k + 3}$$

After trying to decompose it a little bit I ended up with 1/64 $\sum\limits_{i=400}^{2000}  1/8^{2k}2^{4k}$

But I can't really get past, this... I took calculus a long time ago (and I'm not even sure I need calculus stuff for this)...

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=400}^{2000}  2^{3 - 4k}/8^{2k + 3}
= 2^3/8^3 \sum_{i=400}^{2000}  \frac 1{8^{2k }2^{4k}}
=\frac 1{64}  \sum_{i=400}^{2000}  \frac 1{2^{6k }2^{4k}}\\
=\frac 1{64}  \sum_{i=400}^{2000}  \frac 1{2^{10k}}
$$
it is also
$$
\frac 1{64\times 2^{4000}} \frac {1-\frac 1{2^{1601\times 1000}}}{1-\frac 1{2^{1000}}}
$$
which as almost
$$
\frac 1{64\times 2^{4000}} 
$$

Comment: You type too fast!

Comment: just a lot of training ;)